# Need directions on how to create a two dimensional matrix using knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am a newbie to knockout.js.
I am trying to create a matrix like HTML structure. I am trying to start from scratch. User will have a add row button, this will create row. I am able to add multiple rows. Now I am trying to add a column.
The column should basically copy the existing table and make a copy and make it appear in the next column.

I have reached until this point. Link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rush2ashu/QSRBR/6629/)

I am HTML CODE adding the code for easy reading.

```
<div class='liveExample'> 

<div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'> </div>

<button data-bind='click: addRowItem'>
    Add Row
</button>
<button data-bind='click: addColItem'>
    Add Col
</button>
```

This is the Java script code with the knockout.js functions

```
var initialData = [
    { name: "" }
];



var PagedGridModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);


this.addRowItem = function() {
    this.items.push({ name: "New Row" });
};

this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
    data: this.items,
    columns: [
        { headerText: "", rowText: "name"}
    ],
});

};
ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(initialData));
```

Comment: I updated your fiddle as a starting point. It seems to not behave as I would expect it to: http://jsfiddle.net/QSRBR/6631/ The new column only shows up once you add a new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns array in the simplegrid view model needs to be an observableArray otherwise the model will not know it changed. Similar to what you are doing for data, you need to make columns reference an observableArray.

Here is the updated view model:

```
var PagedGridModel = function(items) {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    self.columns = ko.observableArray([
            { headerText: "", rowText: "name"}
        ]);

    self.addRowItem = function() {
        self.items.push({ name: "New Row" });
    };

    self.addColItem = function() {
        self.columns.push({ name: "New Column" });
    };

    self.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: self.items,
        columns: self.columns
    });

};
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I would like to have an option to change the New Row and New Column to some thing more meaningful after the table is created. Say by double clicking a cell, I will be able to edit the name parameter and accept the new name. I tried updating your code further. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rush2ashu/QSRBR/6636/)

Comment: There are some easy plugins i like that do that in a pretty way http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html or you can search knockout binding handler double click and apply that to the simplegrid model